# NPM Excluding files automatically >

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-publish, npm-pack

I am trying to publish a package on npm. It's poppler's pdftotext portable.

The lib folder structure is like this:

```
"lib/libjpeg.so.9",
"lib/libjpeg.so.9.2.0",
"lib/libjpeg.so.9.2.0",
"lib/libpoppler.so",
"lib/libpoppler.so.98",
"lib/libpoppler.so.98.0.0"
```

but when I pack it, npm automatically removed other files and only keeps libjpeg 9.2.0 and libpoppler.so.98.0.0

Why are other files removed? There is no ignore file; no `npmignore` nor `gigignore`.

The type of removed file is `Link to shared library (application/x-sharedlib)` How can I include them as well ?

This is complete package.json

```
{
  "name": "packname",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "description": "dis",
  "main": "index.js",
  "directories": {
    "lib": "lib"
  },
  "files": [
    "bin",
    "lib"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": ""
}
```

Comment: that's interesting.. i'll sit back and watch what the answer'll be

Comment: @TheBombSquad that's really weired i tried to compress my self and the compressors are making the files o bytes in size tried tar and pzip everthing is ruining.